# Are there any valid use cases for replacing a module with a class instance?

Tags: python

### The question

Are there any *valid* use cases for the ol' module switcheroo, where you replace the module with a class instance? By a *valid* use case, I mean a case where it would be generally agreed that using this trick would be the *best* way of solving a problem. For example, the module:

```
VERSION = (1, 2, 8)
VERSION_NAME = '1.2.8'
```

Could be converted to this:

```
import sys

class ConstantsModule(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.VERSION = (1, 2, 8)

    @property
    def VERSION_NAME(self):
        return u'{}.{}.{}'.format(*self.VERSION)

sys.modules[__name__] = ConstantsModule()
```

And now `VERSION_NAME` is a property with logic behind it.

I have googled around for this without finding anything relevant. I learned of this trick in a SO answer I read some time ago, and I know this is something referred to as "black magic" and to be avoided, but I'm curious about the valid use cases.

---

### My specific use case

I have a small problem with one of my modules that could easily be solved if the module was a class instance. I have a "constant" called `VERSION_NAME`, which is a string version of `VERSION`, which in turn is a tuple with my application's version information. The `VERSION_NAME` is used throughout my project and in several other projects based on this one. Now I would like `VERSION_NAME` to include some logic - I would like it to be based on `VERSION` so that I don't have to edit it manually all the time, and I would like it to be formatted slightly differently depending on a couple of environmental circumstances. The way I see it I have two choices:

- Hunt down every use-case of `VERSION_NAME` in my project and all its sub-projects and change it to a function call like `get_version_name`.
- Invoke black magic like shown above.

This question is not about my use case though, this is just an example of what I figure it *could* be used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since everything in Python is an object, there is no black magic about it; this is simply duck typing; if you create an object that walks and talks like a module, then the rest of Python is none the wiser.

However, for your specific use-case, you don't need to resort to this level of deception. Simply calculate version name at import time:

```
VERSION_NAME = u'{}.{}.{}'.format(*VERSION)
```

Nowhere is it stated that module globals can only be literal values; just use a Python expression for them instead.

After all, your `VERSION_NAME` variable is not going to change during the lifetime of your program, you only need to generate it *once*. Use a property only when you need an attribute that needs to be re-calculated every time you access it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it needs to be changed after import time, but it should read `u'{}.{}.{} debug'` if the application is in debug mode and a couple of other variations in different circumstances. Thanks for your answer! :-)